# How to distinguish if styled component was created with React component or with another styled component / native tag

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

I have a very sophisticated component, and I want to prevent passing React components and styled component that were created with React components there. The only components I want to allow are 1) other "simple" styled components 2) native tags (like div). 
For example:

```
function SophisticatedComponent({
  element,
}) {
  if (isReactComponent(element)) {
    throw new Error('React components are forbidden!');
  }
  ...
}


function ReactComponent() {
  return (
    <div/>;
  );
}

<SophisticatedComponent element={<ReactComponent/>}/> // THROW

<SophisticatedComponent element={<div><ReactComponent/></div>}/> // OK

const StyledComponent = styled.div``;
<SophisticatedComponent element={<StyledComponent><ReactComponent/></StyledComponent>}/> // OK

const StyledReactComponent = styled(ReactComponent)``;
<SophisticatedComponent element={<StyledReactComponent/>}/> // THROW
```

How can I write this `isReactComponent` function to distinguish between React components and styled components?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the function:

```
function isReactComponent({type}) {
  if (typeof type === 'string') { // <div><ReactComponent/></div>
    return false;
  }
  if (typeof type === 'object') { // <ReactComponent/>
    return true;
  }
  if (typeof type === 'function' && typeof type.target === 'string') { // <StyledComponent><ReactComponent/></StyledComponent>
    return false;
  }
  if (typeof type === 'function' && typeof type.target === 'object') { // <StyledReactComponent/>
    return true;
  }
}
```